# How to send multiple values to kendo multiselect from selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, kendo-ui, selenium-webdriver

I want to sent more than one value to `Kendo Multiselect` element.
Whenever I use the Following function

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(String.Format("$('#   {0}').data('kendoMultiSelect').value({1});", "TagName", "Value"));
```

I am able to send only value once   if I try to send another value first one is deleted ie whenever I try to send new values the older ones get deleted.
Html Code:-

```
<div class="k-multiselect-wrap k-floatwrap" unselectable="on">
    <ul id="ProfileEditSharedModel_SelectedIndustrySectorIds_taglist" class="k-reset" unselectable="on" role="listbox">
        <li class="k-button" unselectable="on">
            <span unselectable="on">Sector 1</span>
            <span class="k-icon k-delete" unselectable="on">delete</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input class="k-input" style="width: 25px;" accesskey="" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="ProfileEditSharedModel_SelectedIndustrySectorIds_taglist ProfileEditSharedModel_SelectedIndustrySectorIds_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false">
    <span class="k-icon k-loading k-loading-hidden"></span>
</div>
<select id="ProfileEditSharedModel_SelectedIndustrySectorIds" class="bigselect" name="ProfileEditSharedModel.SelectedIndustrySectorIds" multiple="multiple" data-val-required="*" data-val="true" data-placeholder="Select Sectors..." data-role="multiselect" style="display: none;" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
    <option value="1">Sector 1</option>
    <option value="2">Sector 2</option>
    <option value="3">Sector 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: We're going to need more information to work with.  A link, or HTML, would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can send an array in the value method

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(String.Format("$('#   {0}').data('kendoMultiSelect').value([1,2,3]);", "TagName", "Value"));
```